# "func --version" command from cmd returns CommandNotFoundException. Why func command is not working from commandline?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

func : The term 'func' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- func --version
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (func:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

from commandline:
func --version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have installed the **Azure Functions Core Tools** in your System.
*Go to Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features >*

[image]

and then you check the function version from the command prompt:

[image]

If the above tool is not installed, you can install from this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4,macos,csharp,portal,bash#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools).